# Need uppate SQL in SQL within table

Tags: python

I have 2 columns in my table `Office` (`Cust_id`, `customer`)

The data is like below, I want to update the `cust_id` for the customer who have nulls, because I got in late the `cust_id` in the table ,

EX: I need an update script to search the customer who has null `cust_id` and search the `cust_id` and update 
Here DDD customers (`cust_id = 4`) so i need a script to update that

```
cust_id, Customer
1    AAA
2    BBB
3    CCC
null DDD
null EEE
4    DDD
5    CCC
7    EEE
```

Comment: Your table allows duplicate `cust_id`?

Comment: yes it allows dup cust_id !

Comment: Why would you have two rows for the same customer? This seems like a database normalization problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UPDATE` with a self-JOIN:

```
UPDATE Office AS o1
JOIN Office AS o2 ON o1.Customer = o2.Customer
SET o1.cust_id = o2.cust_id
WHERE o1.cust_id IS NULL
AND o2.cust_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar for the quick turnaround i will try this now